# call signalR server in PC from ios client in Mac

Tags: ios, asp.net, swift, signalr

I got this server code form [here](https://github.com/adamhartford/SignalRDemo) and this client from same author [here](https://github.com/adamhartford/SwiftR)

so the .Net signalR server running on PC. The signalR is self-hosted in console application. The client is an ios Client written in Swift in my iMac. I am trying to make the code in Mac to see code in PC. 
all the examples I've found are about calling the signalr from the same server, which is not helpful. My server url is: http://locahost:8080 and signalR on my pc is like so:

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // 127.0.0.1 myserver.com in /etc/hosts
        // Or change myserver.com to localhost
        // Using myserver.com instead of localhost to capture requests in Charles Proxy
        string url = "http://localhost:8080";
        using (WebApp.Start (url)) {
            Console.WriteLine ("Server running on {0}", url);
            Console.ReadLine ();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the method I am trying to hit ('abc' is my server name):

```
// Simple example...
[CustomAuthorize]
public class SimpleHub : Hub
{
    public void SendSimple(string message, string detail)
    {
        var clients = Clients.All;
        Clients.All.notifySimple (message, detail);
    }
}
```

Now the goal is really to hit it from an ios client in the iMac:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Make sure myserver.com is mapped to 127.0.0.1 in /etc/hosts
    // Or change myserver.com to localhost or IP below

    // Default is false
    SwiftR.useWKWebView = true

    // Default is .Auto
    SwiftR.transport = .ServerSentEvents

    // Hubs...
    hubConnection = SwiftR.connect("http://abc:8080") { [weak self] connection in
        connection.queryString = ["foo": "bar"]
        connection.headers = ["X-MyHeader1": "Value1", "X-MyHeader2": "Value2"]

        // This only works with WKWebView on iOS >= 9
        // Otherwise, use NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(["UserAgent": "SwiftR iOS Demo App"])
        connection.customUserAgent = "SwiftR iOS Demo App"

        self?.simpleHub = connection.createHubProxy("simpleHub")
        self?.complexHub = connection.createHubProxy("complexHub")

        self?.simpleHub.on("notifySimple") { args in
            let message = args![0] as! String
            let detail = args![1] as! String
            print("Message: \(message)\nDetail: \(detail)\n")
        }
```

but when I try to initiate the connection, I get this error in Swift:

> SwiftR unable to process message 4eg2u0fw: Error Domain=WKErrorDomain
>   Code=5 "JavaScript execution returned a result of an unsupported type"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=JavaScript execution returned a
>   result of an unsupported type} Disconnected.

Any idea on how to fix this!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've switched direction and went exploring with using this signal code instead: [Tutorial: Getting Started with SignalR 2](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr). I hosted it in azure and was able to call it from WKWebView code in Swift. Check my threads. They have tons of code there about that.

Comment: Note that the code from that tutorial uses SignalR 2.0.0. By default, SwiftR currently expects 2.2.0 unless configured otherwise.